# How to initialize LocalDateTime as TIMESTAMP in mysql with hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

If I want `LocalDateTime` fields to always be of type `TIMESTAMP` in a `mysql` database: can I do better than having to constantly define the `@Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL")` among various classes?

```
@Entity
public class MyTable {
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL")
    private LocalDateTime mymodification;
}
```

The same `@Column` definition has to be repeated over and over for each class that should save a `LocalDateTime` as timstamp instead of `datetime`...

Comment: Since it's LocalDateTime, wouldn't MySQL's "DATETIME" type work better, since neither stores timezone information? Timestamp is meant for when you need to use it in potentially different timezones (or same TZ, but different DST). You may not need column definition at all.

Comment: I only use the field to track the latest modification of a certain field (or of the row). Is `DATETIME` more appropriate here? I don't know, but I'm open for suggestions if so.

Comment: Then instead of `LocalDateTime` you should probably use `OffsetDateTime` and `TIMESTAMP`, along with the `@Version` annotation. Hibernate 5.2 supports those types for that annotation.

Answer (score 0):

[InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS](https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.3/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_mapping_inher.html) will remove redundancy and [@PrePersist](https://vladmihalcea.com/prepersist-preupdate-embeddable-jpa-hibernate/) will instantiate the `LocalDateTime`

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DateHolder {
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL")
    private LocalDateTime myModification;

    //Getters And Setters ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
}

@Entity
public class MyTable extends DateHolder {

    @PrePersist
    public void prePersist() {
        setMyModification(LocalDateTime.now());
    }
}
```